# Swiftui slow scroll with a long list of items macos

Tags: list, macos, performance, swiftui

I'm having an issue when scrolling in my app. It has a long list of items (~300) and when I scroll it is very slow.
I tried a lot of things like switching to lazyvstack, adding an id to the list, using ScrollBar and none of them seem to work.
It is a macos app using swiftui 2.0

Comment: Not one of SwiftUI's finer points on the Mac, unfortunately. I ran across a blog post recently (which I can't seem to find immediately) in which the one part of the app that they ditched SwiftUI was replacing a `List` with a wrapped `NSTableView` for exactly that reason.